# Why empty summary text on CheckBoxPreference has height on some devices?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-layout

I'm trying to display a summary text on a `CheckBoxPreference` when some conditions are met, regardless the state of the check box.
When i don't need the summary text to show up, I set it to empty string and it's working fine.
The problem I have is that on some devices such as Galaxy S3 with 4.3, even though the summary text is empty, it takes height space and the outcome is as follows:

[image: Example CheckBoxPreferences]

On LG G3 & Galaxy S3 4.4, there is no extra height for this blank text.

```
                <CheckBoxPreference
                android:layout="@layout/preference_with_value"              
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:key="screenshot"
                android:switchTextOff="OFF"
                android:switchTextOn="ON"
                android:title="Screenshot" />  
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:layout="@layout/preference_with_value"
                android:defaultValue="false"
                android:key="colorphoto"
                android:title="Color Photo" />
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please add your xml code as well

Comment: Instead of empty string, try with null: `setSummary(null)`

Comment: @ozbek Thank you ozbek!
Setting the string to null did the trick.
Please add an answer so i can accept it.
Lokesh Thank you too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I have is that on some devices such as Galaxy S3 with 4.3, even though the ***summary text is empty***, it takes height space

An empty text is still a *text* and, probably, Android 4.3 is treating it the same way as normal string. Please use `null` if you do not want any summary text:

```
checkBoxPreference.setSummary(null);
```